# NumPy for setting indices to rows and columns

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I have a NumPy zero matrix:

```
import numpy as np

z = np.zeros((3,3), dtype=int)  # array([[0, 0, 0],
                                #        [0, 0, 0],
                                #        [0, 0, 0]])
```

Next, I have some index and some values:

```
idx = np.array([[0, 0],
                [1, 1],
                [1, 2],
                [2, 2]])

v = np.array([1, 3, 7, 2])
```

Is there any NumPy function that can set the index value to the my value?  To get as following:

```
z = array([[1, 0, 0],
           [0, 3, 7],
           [0, 0, 2]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want to `fancy index`

```
n[idx[:,0], idx[:,1]] = v

array([[1, 0, 0],
       [0, 3, 7],
       [0, 0, 2]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this via NumPy's [indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing), where you specify an indexer for each axis as a NumPy array:

```
>>> row, col = idx.T
>>> z[row, col] = v

>>> z
array([[1, 0, 0],
       [0, 3, 7],
       [0, 0, 2]])
```